# Heart {Don't / Doesn't} Lie

Tags: sentence-construction, conjugations

I just have heard a song "Heart Don't Lie".
And I'm curious to know, how has it used? grammatically.

> "Heart **Don't** Lie"
>
> "Heart **Doesn't** Lie."

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/39129/she-dont-know-that-shes-a-lucky-girl

Comment: Can you tell us _which_ song you are referring to? As @J.R. points out, the meaning is actually different in different songs.

Comment: La Toya Jackson - Heart Don't Lie.

Comment: Another related discussion:  "[She don't know she's beautiful.](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34571#34572)"

Answer (score 4):

People will often argue about the best way to describe this kind of language – *colloquial, informal, non-standard, misconjugated, ungrammatical, uneducated, slang, street talk, backwoods talk* – yet most natives will agree that it's perfectly acceptable in many contexts, such as informal speech, literature, and song lyrics.

Of course, the proper way to have subject-verb agreement would be to say either:

> Hearts don't lie.

or:

> The heart doesn't lie.

but musicians are singing about emotions, not grammar, so it "ain't" surprising to hear less-than-impeccable grammar when singers exhibit their emotions while crooning into their microphones.

Comment: How about it being an imperative? I don't know the song, but the only thing missing would be an arguable comma for the sentence to be grammatical by any standard.

Comment: @oerkelens - I noticed your answer and I think that's a clever take on it. "Heart, don't fail me now!" is indeed grammatical, so, without punctuation, your idea is within the realm of possibility. As a matter of fact, the song by [California Dreams](http://www.lyricsfreak.com/c/california+dreams/heart+dont+lie_21005804.html) seems to use the imperative structure, while the [LaToya Jackson](http://www.lyricsbox.com/la-toya-jackson-lyrics-heart-dont-lie-n3rj5rx.html) song seems to use the "informal conjugation" – so either one is plausible, I guess :^)

Answer (score 2):

There are several options, and without more context we do not know which one is correct.

As it stands, the sentences is an imperative:

> Heart, don't lie!

Meaning that you tell a heart that it should not lie. Compare to:

> Johnny, don't sit on the grass!

If the phrase is part of a longer sentence, it could be this:

> My heart doesn't lie.

That is a simple present.

In some dialects of English (and in some cases of poetic license in songs), the normal third-person form is not used.
That means that you will sometimes see these sentences:

> He doesn't know that.
>   He doesn't work here.
>   She doesn't like running.

as

> He don't know that.
>   He don't work here.
>   She don't like running.

Keep in mind that that form is considered *wrong* by a lot of speakers, and certainly should be avoided in formal contexts!

Comment: Yeah, I have heard *MJ* singing *She don't believe!* in his melodious track *Who is it!*

Answer (score 0):

He don't or He doesn't?

He doesn't would be correct. For example: He don't wanna do the dishes. This basically means: He do not wanna do the dishes. That would be incorrect.

If you use He doesn't wanna do the dishes. This would mean: He does not wanna do the dishes. This would be correct.

Comment: It is not incorrect to speakers of that dialect.