# Using 'she don't care' in The Beatles' song 'Ticket to Ride'

Tags: word-usage, negation, informal-language, lyrics, dialect

> She's got a ticket to ride,
>   She's got a ticket to ride,
>   She's got a ticket to ride,
>   But she **don't** care.

It sounded odd to me. So why is it used that way?

Comment: Nina, You can find your answer at http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154355/he-doesnt-vs-he-dont

Comment: Also see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4578/which-is-correct-he-dont-or-he-doesnt

Comment: Also here: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/39129/she-dont-know-that-shes-a-lucky-girl  and here: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26382/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-dont-instead-of-doesnt-in-this-phrase-but-s for answers on ELL itself.

Comment: Another example is the song "Teardrops" by Womack & Womack - *And the music don't feel like it did when I felt it with you*

Comment: It is fairly common to hear "he don't" and "she don't" in song lyrics. Many songwriting and music-making traditions originated from socioeconomic groups who use non-standard English dialects. This includes rock-and-roll, the blues, country music, jazz, hip hop and many others. British groups like the Beatles and Rolling Stones were heavily influenced by American music and often sang with American accents. However in everyday life this usage of "don't" should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

'doesn't care' is the correct form.  But, the **don't** form is called [nonstandard](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#nonstandard) English and is commonly used among native English speakers.

Comment: The question is about don't vs. doesn't. The OP probably knows these are contractions, so this answer isn't helpful.

Comment: I've corrected my answer

Comment: This is bad English but used sometimes this way amongst native speakers